# ui-router force remove old DOM from document BEFORE appending new DOM?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular to build an SPA. There is only one `ui-view` in my app.

```
<section class="main-content" ng-class="{'menu-open': isSideNavOpen && !floatWithMenu}">
    <div ui-view class="content-inner"></div>
</section>
```

And I defined several states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        url: '/home?tab',
        templateUrl: AppInfo.assetPath + '/partials/workspaces/workspaces-default.html',
        data: {
            contentToken: AppInfo.CBAC.Welcome
        }
    })
    .state('workspaces', {
        reloadOnSearch: false,
        url: '/workspaces?tab',
        templateUrl: AppInfo.assetPath + '/partials/workspaces/workspaces-view.html',
        data: {
            contentToken: AppInfo.CBAC.Workspace.UsingWorkspace
        }
    })
```

They have nearly the same HTML:

```
<!-- workspaces-default.html -->
<div style="height:100%">
    <x1-workspaces editable="false"></x1-workspaces>
</div>

<!-- workspaces-view.html -->
<div style="height:100%">
    <x1-workspaces editable="true"></x1-workspaces>
</div>
```

The only difference is the attribute `editable`. If it's `true`, a function in `x1WorkspacesCtrl` (`x1-workspaces` directive controller) will run and queries DOM elements from it's template.

**The problem**, is that when url changes from `/home` to `/workspaces`, the old DOM is still in document while new DOM has been appended and fires `x1WorkspacesCtrl`. This makes `document.querySelectorAll` returns wrong collection.

[image]

I know I can fix it by using a more specific selector, such as `"x1-workspaces[editable='true'] .workspaces"`. But I think it's quite dirty.

I'm wondering whether I could **force remove old DOM from document before appending new DOM**? I searched for a while and read the ui-router docs, but couldn't find an answer. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You could inject $element into the controller. It would return the current element that the controller is attached to.

Comment: This can solve the particular problem, but I still suffer from the timing issue with other states, which are more complicated. So I'd like to know if I can fix the timing issue, that's my root cause.

Comment: when you say timing issue, are you referring to how the ui-router clone the ui-view and append to it before destroying the old view? As far as i know, thats how the ui-router handles state transition.

If you are worried about having two different state showing up together in a split second. you could maybe try using css position so that when the new state is cloned, it is stacked on top of the old state.